# Issue: Violation of Interfering with Apps, Third-party Ads, or Device Functionality policy

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-services

i tried just to publish an update of my app in the Google Play Store, i didn't change anything in the code, just incremented the 'version Code' in gradle and published the app, but the app got rejected (3 times now) because of this policy violation:

> ### Issue: Violation of Interfering with Apps, Third-party Ads, or Device Functionality policy
>
> Ads associated with your app must not interfere with other apps, ads, or the operation of the device, including system or device buttons and ports. This includes overlays, companion functionality, and widgetized ad units. Ads must only be displayed within the app serving them.
>
> Next steps:
>
> 1- Read through the Interfering with Apps, Third-party Ads, or Device Functionality policy and make appropriate changes to your app.
>
> 2- Be sure to remove any ads that appear after the user has exited the app, or 
>    after the user has pressed the back button to exit the app.
>
> 3-
>   Make sure that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies. Additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy violations.
>
> Sign in to your Play Console and submit the update to your app.

i have asked the support for more informations about my app, why it get rejected, hence no ads are shown, when a user leave the app. but it's frustrating to get just the standard answer, as if we are talking just with robots.

here is the answer of the so called "Google Support":

> ... Thanks again for contacting Google Play team.
>
> As much as I'd like to help, I’m not able to provide any more information or a better answer to your question. In our previous email, I made sure to include all the information available to me...
>
> If you have a different question about the Play Developer Console, please let me know.

My App is a Quotes App. in the MainActivity there is a RecyclerView, where all the quotes are Listed, when a user click on a quote, it opens a viewPager-Activity where the user can see the quote and scrolle horizontally to see other quotes.

in the MainActivity there is a banner-Ad at the bottom of the screen. i count how many times a user click on a quote, if the counter goes to  5 i show an interstitial between MainActivity and the viewPager-Activity.

here is the code of the interstitial Ad in the mainActivity.
maybe you guys can see, if my App really violate the Policy mentioned above.

```
protected void onCreate(...){

 //Interstitial
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_interstitial));
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
        });

...

}
```

and when a user click on a quotes, i use this code to show the interstitial ad

```
@Override
    public void onRecyclerViewItemClicked(int itemIndex) {
        if(imageClickedAdsCounter % 5 == 0) { // if it's the fifth time a quote is clicked
            showInterstitialAds();
        }
        ++imageClickedAdsCounter;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageViewPagerActivity.class);
        ...
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void showInterstitialAds(){
        if(mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
```

i don't habe any implementation of the `onBackPressed()`method.

i'm really frustrated right now, first because the so called "google Support" doesn't help at all !!!
and because i don't know what code should i change to be able to update the app. 
so any help will be really appreciated.
thank you in advance

Comment: Did your app takes any user inputs ? Then u need to provide privacy policy link in your app.

Comment: @PranavVR no, nothing like this. But still i have already provided the url to the privacy policy in google play and the app itself

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue the problem was my ad was also showing when user minimize my app I solved the problem by checking if my app is in background

Add library in your build.gradle

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$arch_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"
```

Then when calling mInterstitial.show() check for if app is not in background

```
    if(ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)) {
    
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Log.d("AppInBackground", "App Is In Background Ad Is Not Going To Show");
    }
```

For more information about arch_version and lifecycle_version versions to use check this link : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. i didn't know about it. for now i have solved the issue as i described it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57251947/uncaught-exception-thrown-by-finalizer-all-webview-methods-must-be-called-on-th/57308639#57308639)

Answer (score 0):

I have just received
Issue: Violation of Interfering with Apps, Third-party Ads, or Device Functionality policy

But my application update has no AdMob. I dont have any ad on the app because it is a paid app. Customers do not want ads on app as you know.
I did not receive any explanatory response yet from Google side.
If someone has solution or if it is a general problem on the Google side, please reply

Second, it is said that I can upload the update the app after the fix but whenever I upload new update an automatic reply email is sent saying the same violation issue.
How can I update my app?
Thank you

Thank you.

Comment: so it's the violation mentioned here  ? https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/ads/#!?zippy_activeEl=interfering#interfering

if you don't have any ads in you App, i don't really know why you get this violation at all.

Comment: how were you able to solve this issue? My app don't have adMob and i am getting this error as well.
Can you help?

Comment: I am not sure how I fixed the issue. I dont realy know what was the real cause of it. but first I removed references of all unused Activities from manifest which also contains AdActivity (previous version of Admob used this activity), I added new release of Admob library and implement it @FahidNadeem . Also be sure that onstop and onpause methods don't call another activity.

Comment: same here. I am getting this issue and I don't have any admob at all.... Did someone solved this and can help?

Comment: I think I solved the issue.I say so because I tried to publish many times after various updates of my app. I changed every possibility to find the real cause of the problem. My case is that there is an Async in onCreate(). I moved admob initialization from onCreate() to the end of Async method. Also be sure that you must send your update after there is no waiting status in your publish process. I said this because if you send an update after first removal notification email and the status is still waiting for process you will probably be rejected even if you send a compliant update

Comment: @Cenker have you find any solution i face same issue i didn't show any ads on edit my all ads show between two activity change. already try to upload 4 to 5 time but same mail .on support mail i didn't get any proper answer.

Comment: Hi Guys, i resolved it using this solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57251947/uncaught-exception-thrown-by-finalizer-all-webview-methods-must-be-called-on-th/57308639#57308639