# android issue:violation of Interfering with Apps, Third-party Ads, or Device Functionality. any suggestion how to fix this violation

Tags: android, admob, google-play-console

I received this policy violation email from google play console

I changed my implementation of interstitial ads, still app got removed.
completely removed interstitial ads from my app received removal again.
updated Gradle "compileSdkVersion", "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads" etc still got removal.
removed all unused activities and imports.
updated my ads implementation to the latest code snippets by google. 
I have no fragment dialogs (some answers suggested that it is linked to this violation also) in my app.
also removed "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" from the manifest.

in short. I have tried all solutions available online
but I am still getting this violation. I contacted google support team but they simply forward the same app removal email.

here are my manifest permissions

```
      <uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
```

Gradle dependencies

```
 dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
implementation 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.13'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Do you have a good reason for having the `DISABLE_KEYGUARD`, `REORDER_TASKS` and `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permissions?

Comment: Did you managed to solve the issue? I am facing the same thing

Comment: Maybe this might work for you. We're having the same issur https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57251947/uncaught-exception-thrown-by-finalizer-all-webview-methods-must-be-called-on-th/57308639#57308639