# Don't update app: Fix the policy violation with your app

Tags: android, ads, google-ads-api

The application worked fine for half a year, I tried to upload an update, everything was as usual, but the console received "We have determined your app contains code to facilitate Ad Fraud", although I almost did not change anything. The only change that had at least some relation to the advertisement, after the splash, an advertisement appears, after it is closed, it shows the main screen of the application, it was decided to extend the display time of the splash screen, so a slight delay was added so that the advertisement had a little more time to load. After that, the update failed.
We wrote in support, after almost 2 weeks, they replied:

"I’ve reviewed your appeal request and found that your app still violates Google Play Policy. I’ve included details below about the specific issue with your app and what you can do to get your app back on Google Play.

Step 1: Fix the policy violation with your app

During review, we found that your app violates the Ad fraud policy:

Your app is not compliant with the Ad Fraud policy. Ad fraud is strictly prohibited. Ad interactions generated for the purpose of tricking an ad network into believing traffic is from authentic user interest is ad fraud, which is a form of invalid traffic.

Ads should not be shown in a way that results in inadvertent clicks. Forcing a user to click an ad or submit personal information for advertising purposes before they can fully use an app is prohibited.
Ads should not appear after the user has exited the app, or after the user has pressed the back button to exit the app.
Ads associated with your app must not interfere with other apps, ads, or the operation of the device, including system or device buttons and ports.

This includes overlays, companion functionality, and widgetized ad units. Ads must only be displayed within the app serving them. You can refer the attached screenshot for additional information.

You can read through the Ad Fraud policy page for more details and examples of common violations.

Please update your app to fix this issue. You may also want to double check that your app complies with all other Developer Program Policies, as additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy violations.

Step 2: Submit an update to your app

To submit an updated app bundle or APK:

Prepare your updates.
Create a new release using the compliant app bundle or APK. Be sure to create the new release on the same track(s) as the non-compliant app bundle or APK, increment the version number, and set the release to 100% rollout.
Follow the on-screen instructions to add APKs or app bundles, then review and roll out your release.
Please let me know if you have any other questions. Thanks for working with us to fix the policy issue and for your continued support of Google Play."

It seems like the application does not break anything, but I came across this answer [Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer: All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57251947/uncaught-exception-thrown-by-finalizer-all-webview-methods-must-be-called-on-) th / 57308639 # 57308639 it is possible if the application is minimized and the advertisement is loaded and is shown not in the application. Or, due to problems with the connection, it does not show ads immediately after the splash, but passes it to the main screen and then it already shows that it also seems to be wrong, but then problems with the update appeared earlier. Could any of this be a problem? What else could be the problem? Maybe someone did something similar, please tell me what are the solutions?

Comment: I have a same problem. did you found any solution ?

Comment: @skpanchal, Unfortunately, we could not find a normal solution, I had to revert the version

Comment: Did anyone find a solution yet?

Comment: @SagarBalyan Unfortunately, as I said earlier, I had to revert the version. I got this error even when I reduced the amount of ads, since Google sends a template letter, it's not always clear why this is happening

Comment: @Binary I am just using a banner ad at the bottom, and an interstitial ad which shows at the very start of the app. i.e. oncreate. Is this interstial ad creating the problem maybe...i am thinking? Are we allowed to show an interstitial on the very start of the app?

Comment: @SagarBalyan I'm not one hundred percent sure about immediately after launching the application, but many applications display ads after the splash screen.

Comment: @Binary I dont have a splash screen.

Comment: @SagarBalyan Then I suggest giving it a try, since I haven't seen applications that launch ads right away.

Comment: Hi! Binary, 
Did you find a way to avoid this issue?
We got the same issue and it's really hard to guess what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Update Admob library to 19.7.0 or later and follow the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migration) to update [Rewarded](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-fullscreen) and Interstitial Ads in the app.

Comment: Admob version is not any case here, I am using 20.3.0 but still fetch this rejection.